# my Data (texts in Persian) stores in ??? in mysql even after change charset to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql

I have written An android app that connects to database for `Add`| `Delete` | `Edit` data.

My app and sever side php scripts works fine but after I reset my server from directadmin, some fields in some tables in mysql converted to ?. I check that tables and I saw their charsets changed to `utf8mb4`. I changed their charset to `UTF8-General-ci` and I do repair and optimize, But after I save a name in **Persian**

*(something like Arabic characters)* after some time it convert to ? automatically!

So what's the problem? what's your solution?

Comment: It is better to contact your server administrator to see if there happens any possible changes [after a certain period] to the DB or not.

Comment: i contacted to Server Administrator but they said me this problem is not related to them! :(

Comment: @MostafaTalebi may I have your skype account ?!

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 try `utf8_unicode_ci` instead of `UTF8-General-ci`. also if you use of *php*, put this line before inserting (or after connecting): PDO: `$dbh->exec("set names utf8");`, MySQL: `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");`

Comment: @Sajad instead of names i must put table name?

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 no, just write this `$dbh->exec("set names utf8");`

Comment: @Sajad ok. o also tested utf8-unicode-ci and notthing changed :(

Comment: do you use of what database management ?! phpmyadmin ? If yea, what version ?

Comment: @Sajad if u can tell what i can do in phpmyadmin. because my app connected to server via openfire and i have no access to any of its files

Comment: @Sajad yes is use phpmyadmin : Version information: 4.2.13.1

Comment: alright, your ver is acceptable, just try with `EN` characters, are they fine ?! or also they are as `??` sign ?

Comment: EN characters are fine... only persian chars have this problem.. i do what u say and nothings changed !!!! again data converted to ????

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 if English characters stored as well, then your problem is `charset`. there is one approach else for testing, insert Persian characters by handle *(manually)* (via insert tab in phpmyadmin not inserting by php). so ? the characters are stored in what form? `???` or fine ?

Comment: @Sajad i tested this before and after some time data converts to ???

Comment: ow ! then I don't know what should I say anymore!